# Excerpt selected content automatically

Tags: excerpt

Hi,

as you know, the excerpts will show only a part of the content which always starts at the beginning of the post and ends wherever the character limit is set to. However, I want to show a part of the content that is not at the beginning of the post but defined by delimiters such as “start excerpt” and “end excerpt” so that will become the excerpt. Is there any way to do that? I tried many exceprt plugins but none of them seem to do it.

Also, I know there is box for custom excerpt but that will require me to type again the same thing for every post every time which is time consuming.

Thank you.